# How can I customize button graphics?

Tags: unity, c#, graphics

Inside my buttons I added some variables (as you can see in the code below).

```
public UnityEngine.UI.Text itemInfo;
void Update () {
    itemInfo.text = itemName + "\nCost: " + (costo_stringa = ConvertiroreProiettili.Instance.GetCurrencyInString(costo, false, false))
    + "\nBullets: " + tickValue + "/s" + "\nLiv: " + count;
```

but in this way are one below the other as a list, how do I order them as I will, and also add a picture like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UI button by default contains one image and one label inside it, but you can change that.
You can remove the label from within the button, and instead add several items, making the button a container of several other elements, hence creating whatever layout you want.

It might be easier if you created a panel, put in it all the info you wanted, and then just add the button script to handle clicks.

For more information on how to create a panel, or other complex gui elements, I recommend the UI tutorials:

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui

And there are a few live training sessions that show good exmplaes of stuff you can do with the GUI such as [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/live-training-archive/modal-window), [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/live-training-archive/modal-window-pt2), [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/live-training-archive/panels-panes-windows) and [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/using-the-ui-tools)